# Can I set an invalid value to hardware clock (Real Time Clock) on Linux

Tags: linux

For special testing, I need to set an invalid value to hardware clock time. I have used google but it seems useless.

Comment: What value would be "invalid"?

Comment: @Barmar: On a machine that uses a calendar-based RTC (like x86), February 31st?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but this may be off-topic and better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hardware, this might be impossible.

One way to make it work is to overwrite the function that you use to read the hardware clock. If you have enough tests to make sure the function itself works (and the same is true for the code which uses the function), then you can use the C preprocessor to point your code to a mock implementation that returns illegal values.

That means you need to compile and link a special binary that doesn't call the actual function and run the test with that.